# Symfony 3.1 use custom repository method in a form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an entity:

```
class UserSettings
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $id;
     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="background_color", type="string", length=10)
     */
     private $background_color;

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="text_color", type="string", length=10)
     */
     private $text_color;
     .....
```

and I have a method in the repository of this entity that returns the settings of an user if the record for this user exists otherwise return default values. This is the method:

```
public function getUserSettings( $user_id )
{

    $user_preferences = $this->findOneBy(array('id' => $user_id));

    if($user_preferences){
        return array(
            'user_preferences' => array(
                            'background_color' => $user_preferences->getBackgroundColor(),
                            'text_color' => $user_preferences->getTextColor()
            )
        );
    }else{
        return array(
            'user_preferences' => array(
                            'background_color' => '#000000',
                            'text_color' => '#FFFFFF'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I have a userSettingsType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('background_color', TextType::class)
        ->add('text_color', TextType::class)
    ;
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\UserSettings',
    ));
}
```

and the controller:

```
public function usersettingsAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    $data = $request->request->all();
    $user_settings = new UserSettings();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserSettingsType::class, $user_settings);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user_settings);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('user/user_settings.html.twig', $user_settings );
}
```

The question is: How can I use the repository method getUserSettings() to hydrate the form fields the first time is loaded?.

None of the posts/answers/tutorials/cookbooks I found served me to solve this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your UserSettingsType as service to inject service container to access to doctrine repository and then use `PRE_SET_DATA` form event in your form type (take a look to the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) about formEvents) :

1- Declare your form type as service injecting service container

```
form.type.user_setting:
        class: YourProject\YourBundle\Form\Type\UserSettingsType
        arguments:
            - '@service_container'
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_setting_type }
```

2- Then call it in your controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.user_setting'), $user_settings);
```

3- Finally in your UserSettingsType use the container to access to doctrine and PRE_SET_DATA event to "hydrate the form fields the first time is loaded" :

```
<?php

class UserSettingsType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    //an example to access to your repository
    public funtion myFunction($userId)
    {
        return $this->container
                ->get('doctrine')
                ->getRepository('yourRepository')
                ->getUserSettings($userId);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder
         ->addEventListener(
             FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
             function(FormEvent $event) {
               $form = $event->getForm();

               //get userSettingId if you need it
               $userSetting = $event->getData();
               $userSettingId = $userSetting->getId();

               //you can call 'myFunction' here for example to do want you want

               $form
                 ->add('background_color', TextType::class)
                 ->add('text_color', TextType::class)
               ;
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way?. I don't like to define a service for each form I will have. Is there any way to do the job just in the controller?.

Comment: No, I think if you build your form in your controller you can do the same thing but the method I describe above is the cleanest method, you can easily separate the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DOZ.

You mean writing this:

```
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user_settings_temp = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:UserSettings')->getUserSettings($user->getId());

    $user_settings = new UserSettings();
    $user_settings->setUser( $user->getId() );
    $user_settings->setBackgroundColor( $user_settings_temp['background_color'] );
    $user_settings->setTextColor( $user_settings_temp['text_color'] );
    $user_settings->setFontSize( $user_settings_temp['font_size'] );
    $user_settings->setMenuEmbedded( $user_settings_temp['menu_embedded'] );
    $user_settings->setMenuSide( $user_settings_temp['menu_side'] );
    $user_settings->setShowImages( $user_settings_temp['show_images'] );

    // Create the form object
    $form = $this->createForm(UserSettingsType::class, $user_settings);
```

In the controller.

I agree is less "elegant" but I thing is clearer to maintain.